# Heroku ChatOps (Slack Integration) - route production events only

Tags: heroku, integration, slack, chatops

From [Heroku ChatOps (Slack Integration)](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/chatops) the only option I could find for routing pipeline notifications to a channel is:

```
/h route PIPELINE_NAME to #CHANNEL_NAME
```

But it is sending too many events.

I'm looking for **production only** events, something like:

```
/h route PIPELINE_NAME in production to #CHANNEL_NAME
```

*** UPDATE: Thu 11 Mar 2021:

I developed a solution and wrote an article about it:
https://blog.loadmill.com/heroku-slack-notifications-using-webhooks-and-aws-lambda-ce632a4021de

Answer (score 2):

I too tried this and after much digging can confirm **it is not currently possible**.

It would be great to get more granularity on notification configurations (at app level instead of only pipeline level). In our case we would like to get only the following notifications:

- Failing staging deploy notifications.
- Successful and failing production deploy notifications.